# NestJS prevent server reloading in development

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a route which creates a new folder inside **public** directory which is a static content served with **app.useStaticAssets**.

The problem is that even if I added the **public** directory inside **exclude** array of both **tsconfig.build.json** and **tsconfig.json**, my server still reloads in development when a new folder is deleted or created inside **public** directory.

I'm missing something ?

**UPDATE:**
**tsconfig.json**

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "public"]
}
```

I mention that **public** folder is outside of the **src** folder. They are on the same level.

Comment: Can you add content of the `tsconfig`-files, please?

Comment: Let me know if the propsed solution works, maybe we can open another ticket on github regarding this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this and found out that this seems to be a common issue -> https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3510

As propsed in the github issue, adding `include` as a workaround seems to fix the problem:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "public"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely disable hot reload temporarily, remove the --watch flag from your start:dev script.

1. Go into package.json
2. Find your "start:dev" script under "scripts"
3. Duplicate your "start:dev" script and rename it - I named it `start:dev-noreload`
   Your script should look something like this:

`"start:dev-noreload": "npm run prebuild && npm run kill:dev-process && npm run build:docker-postgres && env ENV=DEV nest start"`

4. Run your app using

   `npm run start:dev-noreload`

In order to get hot reload back, just run the way you normally do.
Either using `npm start`, or `npm run start:dev`.